# Create entity and return ID

Tags: jpa, db2, jpa-2.0, auto-generate

Using Open JPA 2.0, and database is DB2 9.7. I would like to like to create an entity which includes ID which is Primary Key, and auto generated Identity column and after creating the entity I need to display the ID generated. For this after persisting the entity, I am calling entity.getId().
In the database, I see below query getting executed

```
select ID from final table
     (INSERT INTO WEB.USER (NAME, LOCATION) VALUES (?, ?))
```

Is there any alternate / better way to create an entity and return the generated ID? I would like to avoid `"Select ID from final table"`, as this is expected to have performance impact.

Comment: You could try @TableGenerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Database sequence (`@SequenceGenerator`) to avoid "select ID from final table". This worked fine and `@TableGenerator` would also have sorted this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you retrieve auto generated ID from DB2 and there is nothing you can do about it. Other databases often require extra SQL query, so it's actually even better with DB2, which returns ID immedaitely. I don't think there is a faster way to so this.

Check out [`OPENJPA-736`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-736) where this optimization was implemented.

Comment: thanks for your response. But my DBA is not happy with this. Will it help if I change Identity column to generated sequence? Last option is to replace JPA with direct JDBC execution for this issue.

Comment: It seems that you DBA is Oracle oriented. DB2 is better in this way, because it provides Sequences and Auto generated column for unique IDs. What is the criterion of your DBA for being not happy? did he analyze the access plan of this query? why do you want a sequence? this last implies two access to the database, that increases the IO and probably the network traffic. With the other option, (auto generated) it is just one package transmitted and processed in the database.